# How to specify "play next" in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

When iTunes is playing songs from a Playlist, sometimes I just want to play a song from later in the playlist.  Is there a way to load songs into a queue, or to tell iTunes to play another song next?

I'm using iTunes 10.6.0.40 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use iTunes DJ. Select the playlist that you want from the list in the left-hand corner.
[image: iTunes DJ]
Then, you can right click on a song, and select "Play next in iTunes DJ"
[image: Play next in iTunes DJ]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the [iTunes DJ playlist](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2010/03/itunes-dj-and-the-apple-remote-app.html) feature to do something like this. It's located on the top of the Playlists list.

This let's you:

> Change the list of upcoming songs at any time by adding, removing, or reordering them.

Once you have it enabled, you can right-click a song and choose **Play Next in iTunes DJ**.